# n.getFullYear is not a function error when passing an array with react-google-charts

Tags: arrays, reactjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to view date data in a react-google-chart Calendar chart. I have an array of habits and each habit has an array of completion days. I'm trying to map these completion days in to the Chart component but get an error on the DOM `n.getFullYear is not a function` The problem might be that I don't know how to pass the data to the Chart component the right way, mapping from an array. How should I do this?

Here is my code:

```
//example of dateObj:
habit.completions[0] = { thisYear: 2020, thisDay: 3, thisMonth: 2 }
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from 'react-google-charts';

const Habit = ({ habit, handleRemove }) => {
  if (!habit) {
    return null;
  }


  const completionDays = habit.completions.map(dateObj => {
    return [new Date(dateObj.thisYear, dateObj.thisDay, dateObj.thisMonth), 1]
  })

  const dataNotWork = [
    [
      { type: 'date', id: 'Date' },
      { type: 'number', id: 'Completions'}
    ],
    completionDays
  ]

  const dataThatWorks = [
    [{ type: 'date', id: 'Date' }, { type: 'number', id: 'Completions' }],
    [new Date(2012, 3, 13), 1],
    [new Date(2012, 3, 14), 1],
    [new Date(2012, 3, 15), 1],
    [new Date(2013, 2, 10), 1]
  ]

  console.log('completionDays', completionDays)

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart
        width={750}
        height={350}
        chartType="Calendar"
        loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
        data={dataNotWork}
        options={{
          title: habit.name
        }}
        rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
      />
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleRemove(habit)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Habit
```

Here is a console.log of completionDays before return

```
completionDays 
(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [Wed Apr 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), 1]
1: (2) [Wed Apr 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), 1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mapping looks fine,
I believe it is where you're adding the rows to the data definition here...

```
const dataNotWork = [
  [
    { type: 'date', id: 'Date' },
    { type: 'number', id: 'Completions'}
  ],
  completionDays
]
```

the problem is `completionDays` is an array of arrays.

so instead of passing...

```
[new Date(2012, 3, 13), 1],
[new Date(2012, 3, 14), 1],
[new Date(2012, 3, 15), 1],
[new Date(2013, 2, 10), 1]
```

you're passing...

```
[
  [new Date(2012, 3, 13), 1],
  [new Date(2012, 3, 14), 1],
  [new Date(2012, 3, 15), 1],
  [new Date(2013, 2, 10), 1]
]
```

so it is trying to get a date from an array definition--> `[]`

instead, concatenate the two arrays...

```
var data = [
  [
    { type: 'date', id: 'Date' },
    { type: 'number', id: 'Completions'}
  ],
];

data = data.concat(completionDays);
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! I also had my month and day values mixed in the Date constructor.