# n.getFullYear is not a function error when passing an array to google-charts Calendar

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to render a Calendar Chart, but I face a "n.getFullYear is not a function" error and I can't find what's going wrong.

This is my client part:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"], callback:function(){
            getIt(where.getAttribute('data-chart-uri'), function(status,response){
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response,false);
                var options = Object.assign({title: where.getAttribute('data-chart-title')||''}, response.options);
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
                    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(where);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                });
            });
        }});
```

Note: where is the targeted DOM Element and getIt is a fetch like function.

And this is what is sent by the web service (response):

```
[
    [
        {
            "label": "Date",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "label": "Number of individuals",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    [
        "2021-03-11",
        1
    ],
    [
        "2021-03-24",
        2
    ],
    [
        "2021-03-25",
        1
    ]
]
```

I thought it was the same case like  [n.getFullYear is not a function error when passing an array with react-google-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045149/n-getfullyear-is-not-a-function-error-when-passing-an-array-with-react-google-ch), but not...

For debug purpose,I have added this routine upfront and it works... So the issue it related to the fact that the vizualisation API seems not to consider the 'date' type information. Weird ?

```
 for(var i=1;i<response.length;i++){
      response[i][0]=new Date(response[i][0].split('-'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. As per the Google documentation, dates and times must be parsed when using arrayToDataTable().

> Using the Date constructor is useful when manually constructing your
> DataTable using the addColumn(), addRow(), and addRows() methods, **as
> well as the arrayToDataTable() method**. However, if using JSON to
> specify data, the string representation needs to be used.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes?hl=en